# How can I detect when arbitrary things come into a video stream?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, computer-vision, object-detection

I have seen some javascript implementations of 'object detectors' but they all seem to be limited to just faces or hands or some specific type of gesture.
Is there anyway I can just show "it" say.. some little statue I made when I was a kid and have "it" tell me if it's in an video? I want to basically: have a video stream loaded (for example, the webcam on my laptop) and then, if some *thing* that I have predefined comes into the video, then do something with it.. basically make an HTTP call to some other service I have written.

Is there any "it" that can help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can train a specific object detector for each type of "it":)

If you're using openCV, you can use, for example. the cascade classifier:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html

Comment: This will only work if the object is always in the same angle (for example front view), do not have too much rotation and is not deformable. You will also need a LOT of positive image and a LOT of negative image. Depending on the object, it could work very well so give it a try!